# Laravel and pivot table to relate different model

Tags: laravel, pivot, eloquent

I'm wondering how, but it's bit confusing.

I have fine belongs to many relation between users and groups tables as well as appropriate models for all of that.

But i also have table students, where not all users are student so i students table i maintain user_id field.

My question would be: Can i use pivot table "group_user"  for relations between student and group model, in students table i have "user_id" field? and how?

I tried something like

```
public function students()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('Student','group_user','group_id','user_id');
{
```

but i don't see the way how to tell eloquent not to take students.id but to take students.user_id???

Comment: No, you can't do that easily. You would need to override a few methods on `BelongsToMany` and on your Models, so I wouldn't do that. It's not worth the effort.

Comment: what else could help? how can i easily just fetch those users? any idea?

Comment: You asked if you could use the pivot table, so I don't know which users you want. Rephrase your question and say, what you need exactly.

Comment: I have 4 tables "students" ---> "users"  "subjects" -> "groups"
And there is pivot table between groups and users "group_user"
"students" table just extend some more data for users that are student and same thing with "subjects" table, it extends some data for "groups" since not all groups are "subjects" No i want to list all users belonging to certain subject and related data for them, name(which is in "users" table), student_id(which is in "students" table) and subject's name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these relations:

```
Subject belongsTo Group
Group belongsToMany User
User hasOne Student
```

you can easily do this:

```
$subject = Subject::find($someId);
// of course for multiple subject use eager loading:
// $subjects = Subject::with('group.users.student')->get();

$users = $subject->group->users; // related users

foreach ($users as $user)
{
  $user->student; // null|student model
}
```

Comment: Here is what i have... is that it :???

class Subject extends \Eloquent { protected $fillable = []; public function group() { return $this->belongsTo('Group');}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface { public function student() { return $this>hasOne('Student');}

class Group extends \Eloquent { public function users(){return $this->belongsToMany('User'); }

Comment: But for example i also need student's id :(

Comment: Try it first, then ask. You have student model, so `id` will be there as well.

Comment: $subject = Subject::where('subject_code','=',$id)->first();
  // $subject = Subject::where('subject_code','=',$id)->first()->with('groups.users.students');
$users = $subject->group->users; // related users

foreach ($users as $user)
{
  echo $user->student; // null|student model
}

Comment: nop, it gives me error if i try to get anything beyond $user.. $user->student just error..

Comment: it tries this select "groups".*, "group_user"."user_id" as "pivot_user_id", "group_user"."group_id" as "pivot_group_id" from "groups" inner join "group_user" on "groups"."id" = "group_user"."group_id" where "group_user"."user_id" = '14'

Comment: It won't give any error, but mind that `user->student` might be null, so you can't just call `user->student->id` in a loop. First check if the student exists, like `if ($user->student) $user->student->id`

Comment: this is what i get: Trying to get property of non-object
/var/www/local.space.ssst.edu.ba/app/controllers/SubjectsController.php#61

Comment: you can reach me @ jarek[at]softonsofa.com